# Binary to decimal converter in C doesn't work after a certain number

Tags: c, converters

I've tried making a positive binary to decimal number converter using C, but when i try inputting values higher than 1110011010110001010111 (3779671 in decimal) the program always returns that exact number. My current assignment requires that it works on binary numbers up to 111111111111111111111111111111 (1073741823).

So far, i've tried changing the variable types to any other larger sizes possible, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's the current code:

```
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
unsigned long long int bi, de = 0;    
unsigned long long int x = 0, bases;  

scanf("%llu", &bi); 

for(x=0 ; bi>0 ; x++, bi=bi/10){
    bases = bi % 10;              
    de = de + bases * pow(2,x);

}                       

printf("%llu", de); // imprime o correspondente em decimal

}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The maximum value of a `long long int` is `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`

Comment: You aren't reading the binary value in as as string - you are reading it as a number with digits of 1 and 0 but long long int has a maximum number that it can hold.  Instead read the binary value as a string and it will work.

Comment: Ah, understood, thanks a lot! Do you have any suggestions on how to do the whole mathematical process on a string? I'm thinking i'll have to redo this differently, since i dont think i can just use the "%" and "/" operators on a string.

Comment: I'll make an answer...

Comment: @Barmar Maybe not  [maximum value of a long long int is 18,...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859347/binary-to-decimal-converter-in-c-doesnt-work-after-a-certain-number#comment107676714_60859347) looks like the common max value of an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: ... or use `de = strtoull("111111111111111111111111111111", 0, 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't read the binary number 111111111111111111111111111111 and put it in a unsigned long long integer because the limit for a unsigned long long int is 18446744073709551615, so you need to read the binary number as a string of characters and then convert each character to a numeric digit instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned long long int bin2dec(const char *string, const size_t size)
{
    unsigned long long int bit, value = 0;
    for(size_t index=0;index<size;index++)
    {
        // moving from the end to the beginning, get a character from the string
        // and convert it from a character containing a digit to a number
        bit = string[size-index-1]-'0';

        // in the original question this was: value += bit*pow(2,index);
        // but we can just do this and get the same effect
        // without multiplication or library function
        value += bit<<index;
    }
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    const char * binary = "111111111111111111111111111111";
    unsigned long long int decimal = bin2dec(binary, strlen(binary));
    printf("%llu\n",decimal);
    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/Skh7XKYUU

Comment: Code fails for "binary" above the `unsigned range`.  To work for the `unsigned long long` range, use `unsigned long long bit`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica  the variable `bit` is just one character from the string so it will be either the integer 0 or 1.  I don't understand why it needs to be wider than `short`

Comment: If `index` in `bit<<index` gets greater or equal than `8 * sizeof bit`, the result gets 0. C17 standard 6.5.7 on `E1 << E2`: "If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 * 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." Try your program with some larger input.

Comment: Also, why don't you just shift bit-by-bit from the right into the result?

Comment: @thebusybee ok, wait - so I don't really understand the reasoning for why it should work that way, but you are right `const char * binary = "111111111111111111111111111111";` returns 0 so I need to change it.

Comment: @thebusybee What do you mean shift bit by bit?  I used a string where each binary digit is a character.  Maybe you should write an answer - I would like to see what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all that indexing and adding. You can simply shift in the bits from the right:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned long long int bin2dec(const char *string)
{
    unsigned long long int value = 0;
    while (*string != '\0')
    {
        // make room for the next bit by shifting what is there already
        value <<= 1;
        // *string != '0' gives 1 if the current character is not '0', else 0
        value |= *string != '0';
        string++;
    }
    return value;
}

int main(void)
{
    //                     7  F   C   F   F   4   F   A   F   F   F
    const char * binary = "1111111110011111111010011111010111111111111";
    unsigned long long int decimal = bin2dec(binary);
    printf("%llX\n", decimal);
    return 0;
}
```